# Keep in synch certain parts of master and a branch with Git

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a Phonegap app. I do about 80% of the work on a desktop in Chrome and 20% testing on a smartphone. I'm new to Git and am using it to back up my work. Here is my project structure:

[image]

The problem is that when I want to test on my phone, I need to change the url in each model, some lines in router.js, and link to cordova.js in the index.html file (chrome crashes when i include link to cordova on desktop).

What I would like to do is have the master project, which I test on my desktop, and a branch (with models, router and index changed) which I test on a smartphone. But any changes I make to other parts of the project, I want to update in both master and the branch. Is this possible with Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a branch that tracks `origin/master`:

```
$ git checkout -b --track my-branch origin/master
```

Make the modifications, and then you can

```
$ git pull --rebase
```

to bring in the new changes from `master`, and you can do that whenever you want to update.

See more:

http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/03/09/remote-tracking-branches.html
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Tracking-Branches

I don't know how Phonegap works, but I'd imagine that instead of branching you should be able to have some server-side code deciding what to serve to the client based on the user agent (e.g. whether it's detected to be a mobile browser or not).